# How do I get Javascript to be not case sensitive when it comes to if statements?

Tags: javascript

I fully understand Javascript is case sensitive, but when it comes to if statements Sam does not equal to sam. I created a prompt box calling this function and I would like it to convert sam to Sam or make both True when you type the name into the prompt box.

```
function search(name) {
var ourContacts = contacts.length;
for (var i = 0; i < ourContacts; i++) {
if (contacts[i].name === name) {
printdog(contacts[i]);
}
}
}
```

Here is my whole script if you need it for better understandings.

```
function dog(name, breed, age, color, weight, owner, owneraddress) {
    this.name = name;
    this.breed = breed;
    this.age = age;
    this.color = color;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.owner = owner;
    this.owneraddress = owneraddress;
}
//My Dogs
var sam = {
    name: "Sam",
    breed: "Chihuahua",
    age: 7,
    color: "White",
    weight: "7 lb",
    owner: "Bourton",
    owneraddress: "44 Berkley Drive"
};
var max = {
    name: "Max",
    breed: "Chihuahua",
    age: 4,
    color: "Brown",
    weight: "5 lb",
    owner: "Smith",
    owneraddress: "134 Door Ave"
};

//My array of dogs
var contacts = [sam, max];

function printdog(dog) {
    console.log(dog.name + " " + dog.owner);
}
function list() {
var ourContacts = contacts.length;
for (var i = 0; i < ourContacts; i++) {
printdog(contacts[i]);
}
}
list();
function search(name) {
var ourContacts = contacts.length;
for (var i = 0; i < ourContacts; i++) {
name = name.toLowerCase;
if (contacts[i].name === name) {
printdog(contacts[i]);
}
}
}

<button onclick="search(prompt('Search Dogs Name'))">Search for Dog</button>
```

Comment: Why do you have a `dog` constructor but don't use it?

Comment: I am still learning about objects, so I am not sure.  I just thought it was apart of making objects.

Comment: function printdog(dog) { 
    console.log(dog.name + " " + dog.owner); 
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Javascript [.toUpperCase()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp) method on both operands:

```
if (contacts[i].name.toUpperCase() === name.toUpperCase())
```

Alternatively, you can use the [.toLowerCase()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp) method on both operands:

```
if (contacts[i].name.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase())
```

Comment: Thank you, that works great.  I didn't know you could do that, I thought you could only use one contacts[i].name not two.  That is going to be useful in the future for sure.

Comment: You should not apply this function on the search param each time

Answer (score 4):

you may do something like `.toUpperCase()` on both ends before equality comparer

Answer (score 1):

Just [lower-](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) or [uppercase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) everything (both search and data). You already tried do do this for `name`, but not on `contacts[i].name` (and they're named "Sam" and "Max", so they will never equal a lowercased input string).

Also, you forgot to execute the function - you just got a reference to it.

```
function search(name) {
    var ourContacts = contacts.length;
    name = name.toLowerCase();
//                         ^^
    for (var i = 0; i < ourContacts; i++) {
        if (contacts[i].name.toLowerCase() === name) {
//                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            printdog(contacts[i]);
        }
    }
}
```